# Get the maximum number of simultaneous calls from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find the maximum number of calls on a SIP line from our database. Here is an example of the data:

```
ID  StartTime           EndTime
66  01/03/2018 5:31:18  01/03/2018 5:31:51
66  01/03/2018 5:31:51  01/03/2018 5:32:19
66  01/03/2018 5:32:21  01/03/2018 5:34:10
66  01/03/2018 5:32:31  01/03/2018 5:33:42
66  01/03/2018 5:33:02  01/03/2018 5:33:42
66  01/03/2018 5:33:23  01/03/2018 5:34:10
66  01/03/2018 5:33:45  01/03/2018 5:34:38
66  01/03/2018 5:34:08  01/03/2018 5:34:38
```

The way I calculate this out, visually, the number should be 5.

The closest that I've come so far has returned 4 for this example and is off on other tests as well.   Other code I have tested has been wildly off (by 100s).

```
DECLARE @ReportStartDate datetime, @ReportEndDate datetime,        
@ReportStartTime time, @ReportEndTime time
SET @ReportStartDate='1/3/2018'
SET @ReportEndDate='1/3/2018'
SET @ReportStartTime='05:00:00'
SET @ReportEndTime='06:00:00'

SET @ReportStartDate = (SELECT @ReportStartDate + @ReportStartTime)
SET @ReportEndDate = (SELECT @ReportEndDate + @ReportEndTime);

WITH C1 AS
(
  SELECT startdate AS ts, +1 AS TYPE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY startdate) AS start_ordinal
  FROM table
  WHERE startdate >= @ReportStartDate and startdate <= @ReportEndDate
  and Service_id=66 --hardcoded for testing
  UNION ALL
  SELECT enddate, -1, NULL
  FROM table
  WHERE enddate >= @ReportStartDate and enddate <=    
 @ReportEndDate
  and Service_id=66 -- hardcoded for testing
),
C2 AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(  ORDER BY ts, TYPE) AS start_or_end_ordinal
  FROM C1
)
SELECT MAX(2 * start_ordinal - start_or_end_ordinal) AS mx
FROM C2
WHERE TYPE = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this logic as:

```
with tt as (
      select id, stime as thetime, 1 as inc from t union all
      select id, etime, -1 as inc from t
     )
select top (1) tt.*
from (select tt.*, sum(inc) over (partition by id order by thetime) as overlaps
      from tt
     ) tt
order by overlaps desc;
```

This also returns "4" for your example, but this makes sense to me.

You can test this out on [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3dded71e6399518417301425ab84bedc).